# AngularJS create html/link/anchor from text (escape/unescape html in view)

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, anchor, sanitize, html-escape-characters

I have a controller that has an assigned value:

```
$scope.post = 'please visit http://stackoverflow.com quickly';
```

I have some text in my html:

```
<p>{{post}}</p>
```

I would like to make a clickable link of the url  (surround it with anchor tags).

I tried to change my html to:

```
<p ng-bind-html="post | createAnchors"></p>
```

Here is a simplified example of the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/T3fFt/4/

The question is, how can I escape the whole post text, except for the link, which will be surrounded by anchor tags?
?

Comment: Why is there no accepted answer for this question. At least one of these are Kato approved. Make it so.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you can use Angular's linky filter for this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky

You can use it like so:

```
<p ng-bind-html="post | linky"></p>
```

You'll have to include Angular's sanitize module for linky to work:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'myApp.filters', 
    ...
```

Comment: I think the linky filter has been available since AngularJS 1.0: https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.2/docs/api/ngSanitize.filter:linky

Comment: @Daan I'm on Angular v1.2.21 and it works fine. `<div ng-bind-html="post.Text | linky:'_blank'"></div>`

Comment: A word of warning to anyone wanting to use linkyFilter: It escapes HTML characters so your raw HTML code (but with links) will show up in the html-bound element

Comment: Yes, @Dylanthepiguy, that is the desired behavior for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this replace for the string:

```
'please visit http://stackoverflow.com quickly'.replace(/(http[^\s]+)/, '<a href="$1">$1</a>')
```

then you'll need to use the [`$sce`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce) service, and [`ngBindHtml`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtml) directive.

> `$sce` is a service that provides Strict Contextual Escaping services to
>   AngularJS.

So in your filter you need to wrap links with `a` tags then return a trusted html using `$sce.trustAsHtml`:

```
filter('createAnchors', function ($sce) {
    return function (str) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(str.
                                replace(/</g, '&lt;').
                                replace(/>/g, '&gt;').
                                replace(/(http[^\s]+)/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a>')
                               );
    }
})
```

Working examples: http://jsfiddle.net/T3fFt/11/

Comment: Can you please tell me what functions exactely? I tried a few of them but didn't get it to work.

Comment: did you try `trustAsHtml`?

Comment: Do I get it right: When you set ng-bind-html, Angular will not escape html. When you then manually set $sce.trustAsHtml, this is the same right? So in that case that won't help me

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the rest of the text is not getting escaped. Check http://jsfiddle.net/T3fFt/5/ where another anchor is not escaped. I updated my question with a jsfiddle.

Comment: I've lost you, you do not want to escape the string?

Comment: When someone enters a url in the post, I want them to get anchor tags around them and THAT anchor tag should not be escaped but rendered as HTML. The REST of the post should be escaped, so a user cannot insert <script> tags or something.

Comment: Yes like that, but than I don't want to escape every character myself (what you do now with the `replace(/</g, '&lt;')`) but want to use some function from Angular

Comment: No such function AFAIK.