# How do I create link tags within strings in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, string

I have strings that contains links and I want to make the link clickable. In angular how would I go about doing so.

Here is an example of a string from the json data I have "I’m hosting #AFF Catwalk Show @Bullring on 27th Sept with @BillieFaiers. Find out more here > http://www.clickhereformoreinfo.com"

Basically I want the hashtags, at symbols and the link to all be a tags. Please help been struggling with this for hours now.

Comment: You will use simple Javascript function. Find a regex that catch the link, the hash character and the @. Then use the result to replace them by an `a` tag with the link inside href. Try something then come back with problem/errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Angular from escaping HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778709/prevent-angular-from-escaping-html)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475837/angularjs-create-html-link-anchor-from-text-escape-unescape-html-in-view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

View

```
<div ng-repeat="text in texts">
    <p ng-bind-html="text | parseUrl"></p>
</div>
```

Directive

```
angular.module('filters', [])
    .filter('parseUrl', function() {
        var urls = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;-]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim
        var emails = /(\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/gim

        return function(text) {
            if(text.match(urls)) {
                text = text.replace(urls, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>")
            }
            if(text.match(emails)) {
                text = text.replace(emails, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>")
            }

            return text
        }
    });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/k4vL5yeHHyLqYu7el7b5?p=preview

Comment: What is "comment.body" represent? And I am loading this data from an ng-repeat. How would I grab the string from that?

Comment: Look at this: https://plnkr.co/edit/k4vL5yeHHyLqYu7el7b5?p=preview

Comment: Then please mark as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    var str = "I’m hosting #AFF Catwalk Show @Bullring on 27th Sept with @BillieFaiers. Find out more here > http://www.clickhereformoreinfo.com";
    var subStr = str.split(">");
    $scope.name = subStr[0];
    $scope.link = subStr[1];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{name}}<a href="link">{{link}}</a>
</div>
```